# Javascript - return statement not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, return

I am having a problem with my function. I know that the line to return the variable I want is being reached but it is not returning for some reason. Here is my function:

```
console.log(getLabel(mySelectElementNode)); // this is undefined

function getLabel(element) {
    // This function tries to find the label associated with the select element
    // select.labels is the usual property, but not all browsers support it

    //get the sibling nodes of the label we need
    var siblings = element.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes;
    siblings.forEach(function (elem,ind) {
        if (elem.nodeName=='LABEL') {
            console.log(elem); //I can see this in my browser and it is the label I am looking for
            return elem; // but this return statement does nothing
        };
    });
    console.log('label not found');
}
```

I dont understand why my return statement is not working. I have also tried putting return null; at the end of the function after the console.log statement, but even that didnt work.

Comment: You're returning from inside the anonymous function, not the outer function.

Comment: what do you want with return? end the iteration or return a value for using it further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning from the `forEach` callback, not your `getLabel` function. It's not just you, lots of people make this mistake at some point. :-) Instead, ensure that the `return` is in `getLabel` *outside* of any nested function.

In your case, you don't want `forEach` anyway, you want [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
function getLabel(element) {
    // This function tries to find the label associated with the select element
    // select.labels is the usual property, but not all browsers support it

    //get the sibling nodes of the label we need
    var siblings = element.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes;
    return Array.prototype.find.call(siblings, function(elem) {
        return elem.nodeName == "LABEL";
    });
}
```

`find` was added in ES2015, but can be polyfilled; the link above has a polyfill.

Note that `childNodes` isn't an array, which is why we use `Function#call` above.

If you want to do it without a polyfill, you can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which was added in ES5 (2009):

```
function getLabel(element) {
    // This function tries to find the label associated with the select element
    // select.labels is the usual property, but not all browsers support it

    //get the sibling nodes of the label we need
    var siblings = element.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes;
    var result = undefined; // The default is `undefined`, of course; this is just for clarity
    Array.prototype.some.call(siblings, function(elem) {
        if (elem.nodeName == "LABEL") {
            result = elem;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

`some` calls the callback until it returns a truthy value.

Or of course, a simple `for` loop:

```
function getLabel(element) {
    // This function tries to find the label associated with the select element
    // select.labels is the usual property, but not all browsers support it

    //get the sibling nodes of the label we need
    var sibling;
    for (sibling = element.parentNode.parentNode.firstElementChild; sibling; sibling = sibling.nextElementSibling) {
        if (sibling.nodeName == "LABEL") {
            return sibling;
        }
    }
    return undefined; // Again, just for emphasis/clarity
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are returning from the callback function of the forEach that's why it isn't working fine. Since you are calling getLable hence you have to write the return statement in the scope of getLable function. But your return statement is in the scope of inner callback function. The correct code is as below.

```
console.log(getLabel(mySelectElementNode)); 
// this is undefined
 function getLabel(element) { 
// This function tries to find the label associated with the select element
 // select.labels is the usual property, but not all browsers support it
 //get the sibling nodes of the label we need
var newElem;
 var siblings = element.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes;
 siblings.forEach(function (elem,ind) {
 if (elem.nodeName=='LABEL') {
     newElem = elem;
console.log(elem); //I can see this in my browser and it is the label I am looking for 
return elem; // but this return statement does nothing
 }; }); console.log('label not found'); 
return newElem;
}
```